# WPF Treeview - How to automatically expand parents and select new node

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have model objects set up like so:

```
public class Model
{
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Children{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

This gives me a tree of model objects of arbitrary size and depth. I display these in a WPF TreeView using a hierarchical datatemplate. Because of the ObservableCollection, I can add model objects anywhere in the model tree and the UI will update accordingly.

The annoyance comes because even though a new model object might be added at the third level, for example, it might not be immediately visible.

When a new model object is added anywhere in the tree, I would like the TreeView to automatically select the new node, and expand its parents to that it is immediately visible to the user. This doesn't seem to be immediately obvious.

What I don't want to do is pollute the Model objects with properties which only make sense in a particular WPF control. Nor do I want to add a parent property to the Models.

It seems that this must have been tackled before by someone. Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 properties in your model as below
IsExpanded and IsSelected

and in your treeview ItemContainerStyle add the below setters

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
<Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded}"/>
```

Noe everytime you set these 2 properties in your viewmodels, the corresponding treeviewitem will be selected/expanded

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in my question, I don't want to "pollute the Model objects with properties which only make sense in a particular WPF control. Nor do I want to add a parent property to the Models" - both of which I would need to do to use your suggestion.

Comment: You dont need to add these properties to your models but surely ViewModels can have these properties right?(where all your logic happens). Are you binding your view directly to your models without going through viewmodels?

Comment: Obviously it's a simplified example, but IsSelected and IsExpanded are properties of the View, not the Model/ViewModel. And I would still need to add a way to walk up the tree through the Model's parents to expand each one. Two things which I want to avoid. There are other complicating factors which I left out in the interests of clarity, like my TreeView binds onto the tree of models, but a ValueConverter wraps each one in a ViewModel. A ViewModel knows nothing about it's parent, nor should it need to.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what else to suggest here then. In our project I have implemented these properties in the Collection Item ViewModel and whenever the add Child method is invoked in that ViewModel, I just had to set child.IsSelected = true and this.IsExpanded = true. That has allowed me to expand the node to which a child item has been just added and also to select the child item. Also I dont think there is anything wrong with having two bools controlling the treeview operations in viewmodels(I know it breaks the MVVM pattern a bit but i guess there is a thin line) Good luck

Comment: @RBT You don't pollute the model, nor would you want to bind directly to it. 
That's the entire purpose of a ViewModel...